# mdadm raid 1 array can't mount after resync

Tags: mount, raid, reboot, mdadm

I have a raid one device that works fine with one drive and during the resync after I add the second, but once I reboot I can no longer mount the filesystem.  With only 1 drive in the array (i can remove either one with the same result) I get a /dev/mdxxpxx device that mounts the filesystem fine.  When I add the second drive (while still mounted) it will resync without an issue and I end up with an array marked clean.  But after reboot I no longer see the mdxxpxx device and I am unable to mount the fileystem any longer:

```
root@Watchme:~# mdadm --detail /dev/md0
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sun Nov 14 12:06:40 2021
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 23439733760 (21.83 TiB 24.00 TB)
     Used Dev Size : 23439733760 (21.83 TiB 24.00 TB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sun Nov 14 12:06:40 2021
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : xxxxx:0  (local to host xxx)
              UUID : dde5b8f6:fe3a89e5:f281c9ef:c4433874
            Events : 0

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8        1        0      active sync   /dev/sda1
       1       8       17        1      active sync   /dev/sdb1

root@Watchme:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[1] sda1[0]
      23439733760 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/175 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>

root@Watchme:~# mdadm --examine /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : dde5b8f6:fe3a89e5:f281c9ef:c4433874
           Name : Watchme.wachtveitl.xyz:0  (local to host Watchme.wachtveitl.xyz)
  Creation Time : Sun Nov 14 12:06:40 2021
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 46879467520 sectors (21.83 TiB 24.00 TB)
     Array Size : 23439733760 KiB (21.83 TiB 24.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264080 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 55a52a97:8a7019d0:eab789f9:eb18d6f0

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sun Nov 14 12:06:40 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 96 sectors
       Checksum : dec6072c - correct
         Events : 0


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : dde5b8f6:fe3a89e5:f281c9ef:c4433874
           Name : Watchme.wachtveitl.xyz:0  (local to host Watchme.wachtveitl.xyz)
  Creation Time : Sun Nov 14 12:06:40 2021
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 46879467520 sectors (21.83 TiB 24.00 TB)
     Array Size : 23439733760 KiB (21.83 TiB 24.00 TB)
    Data Offset : 264192 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=264080 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 06ed8c71:b26928da:5b59adf0:5550c044

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Sun Nov 14 12:06:40 2021
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 96 sectors
       Checksum : e4520e1 - correct
         Events : 0


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)

root@Watchme:~# blkid|grep -v loop
/dev/sda1: UUID="dde5b8f6-fe3a-89e5-f281-c9efc4433874" UUID_SUB="55a52a97-8a70-19d0-eab7-89f9eb18d6f0" LABEL="Watchme.wachtveitl.xyz:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="98b9d7e4-1ffe-b34e-8657-e1171fee9eea"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="dde5b8f6-fe3a-89e5-f281-c9efc4433874" UUID_SUB="06ed8c71-b269-28da-5b59-adf05550c044" LABEL="Watchme.wachtveitl.xyz:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member" PARTUUID="966dc93b-3b1b-49b8-8bc3-cda98819cf2c"
/dev/sdc1: UUID="2371e92a-ce66-4367-af04-82d671001eac" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="6a4e6d9f-01"
/dev/sdc5: UUID="909bf5e9-f558-4d26-ac96-ac8f7ff952c5" UUID_SUB="b291a607-c28f-4eab-9ae9-6621f9929cd2" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs" PARTUUID="6a4e6d9f-05"
/dev/sdd1: UUID="054a11be-eb31-480f-b0d9-9de0c9809d8e" UUID_SUB="e61e0ac0-d008-4f47-8517-a854f42dd9cb" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs" PARTLABEL="Test Partition" PARTUUID="086e0cc9-2710-0000-50eb-806e6f6e6963"
/dev/sdd2: UUID="1BFA-08CE" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Test Partition" PARTUUID="07376838-2710-0000-50eb-806e6f6e6963"
/dev/sdd3: LABEL="Win10" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="47F6009C5191E06C" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Test Partition" PARTUUID="07374128-2710-0000-50eb-806e6f6e6963"
/dev/sdd4: UUID="A583-7A72" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Test Partition" PARTUUID="086e33d9-2710-0000-50eb-806e6f6e6963"
/dev/md0: PTTYPE="PMBR"

root@Watchme:~# mount /dev/md0 /media_lv
mount: /media_lv: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/md0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

root@Watchme:~# mount --uuid=dde5b8f6-fe3a-89e5-f281-c9efc4433874 /media_lv
mount: /media_lv: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'.

root@Watchme:~# mount --uuid=dde5b8f6-fe3a-89e5-f281-c9efc4433874 -t ext4 /media_lv
mount: /media_lv: /dev/sda1 already mounted or mount point busy.
```

I have spent hours scouring the internet for solutions, I can remove either drive and the mdxxpxx device comes back and I can mount the filesystem and all the data is fine.  Resyncing is a long process obviously due to the size of the filesystem it takes about 10 hours to complete.  I have tried stopping the array and creating it again with the --assume-clean option (without mounting in between obviously) several times, and have also simply added the second drive in as a hot spare and then adding back to the array and letting it resync which works fine and I can use the data without issues until I reboot then I am stuck again.

I am at a loss of where to go from here and any assistance is greatly appreciated.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no idea what happened but basically I just started from scratch after removing everything including the partitions on the disks and now I get a UUID for /dev/md0 and can mount umount it just fine.  When I originally created the array there was a filesystem on the first disk and I think that MAY have screwed me up because I didn't create a filesystem onto /dev/md0 after since the existing filesystem showed up and could be mounted on the md0p1 device.

Just posting my findings in case it helps someone in the future.